# In unittest, how to pass mock object in unit tests so it can be used in 'with' context?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to write unit test for the following function:

```
def my_func():
    _session, _engine = get_session_and_engine()
    with _session.begin():
        # Some functionality
         pass

    return result
```

My unit test file:

```
@mock.patch('core.my_func_file.get_session_and_engine')
def test_my_func(mock_get_func):
    mock_session = mock.Mock()
    mock_session.return_value = mock_session
    mock_session.__enter__ = mock.Mock(return_value=(mock_session, None))
    mock_session.__exit__ = mock.Mock(return_value=None)

    mock_get_func.return_value = (mock_session, mock.Mock())
    res = my_func()
    assert res is not None
```

When I run this test in pytest, I am getting the following error.

```
   with _session.begin():
       AttributeError: __enter__
         core.my_func_file.py:5024: AttributeError
```

The issue here is we are passing a mock object which is to be used in 'with' context.
At that time, we are getting the above mentioned error.

How to mock such objects so that it can be used in `with` context?

Version information:
python 3.7
pytest 6.2.3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mocking-magic-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the comment of @jonrsharpe

Since `with` context here uses `_session.begin()`, we need to pass the return value for that function.
So after adding
`mock_session.begin.return_value = mock_session` , the test runs fine.

```py
    mock_session = mock.Mock()
    mock_session.__enter__ = mock.Mock(return_value=mock_session)
    mock_session.__exit__ = mock.Mock(return_value=None)
    mock_session.begin.return_value = mock_session
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mocking-magic-methods